# My custom sharepoint 2010 Timer job not running

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-timer-job

I have created a custom timer service to create a list. its scheduled in minute using FeatureActivated event. I could able to globally deploy the solution. But the my timer job is not running. Its showing last run time N/A. Is there any solution?

My Execute method

```
    public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://mymachine:0909");
        Web site = clientContext.Web;

        ListCreationInformation listCreationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
        listCreationInfo.Title = "Test Mailer List";
        listCreationInfo.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.GenericList;
        List list = site.Lists.Add(listCreationInfo);

        Field field1 = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
                  @"<Field Type='Choice'
                  DisplayName='Category'
                  Format='Dropdown'>
             <Default>Specification</Default>
             <CHOICES>
               <CHOICE>Specification</CHOICE>
               <CHOICE>Development</CHOICE>
               <CHOICE>Test</CHOICE>
               <CHOICE>Documentation</CHOICE>
             </CHOICES>
           </Field>", true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
        Field field2 = list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(
            @"<Field Type='Number'
                  DisplayName='Estimate'/>", true, AddFieldOptions.DefaultValue);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

And Event receiver class

```
public class Feature1EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
{


    public const string jobName = "BdayTimer";
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        DeleteJob(webApp.JobDefinitions);
        TimerJobTest myJob = new TimerJobTest(webApp);

        SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
        schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
        schedule.EndSecond = 59;
        schedule.Interval = 1;

        myJob.Schedule = schedule;
        myJob.Update();

    }


    // Uncomment the method below to handle the event raised before a feature is deactivated.

    public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        DeleteJob(webApp.JobDefinitions);
    }

    public void DeleteJob(SPJobDefinitionCollection job1)
    {
        foreach (SPJobDefinition job in job1)
        {
            if (job.Name.Equals(jobName))
                job.Delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy a SharePoint project, you should always restart your `sptimer` process. Try going into the command prompt (with administrator access) and type:

```
net stop sptimerv4
```

then

```
net start sptimerv4
```

Your code should work fine now.

Comment: @user1805285 Did you make sure you deploy your code FIRST before resetting the `sptimer`?

Comment: Yes. I deployed it first and then restart the timer service.

Comment: @user1805285 hmm...then probably there is something wrong with your code

Comment: Its working fine on another server. I dont know whats the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the `Central Administration Pool` on the `Internet Information Services`. It seems to be that the job got stuck. With the pool reset, everything starts working again.